# How to integrate a new authorizer for AWS API Gateway through "Serverless" framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm developing a serverless project using serverless.com framework and I've stumbled upon the case when I have to build an integration Amazon Cognito user Pool with Api Gateway.

How to write a Labmda function and set that function as a new custom authorizer?

Here is a [good example](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3JK25U7Z9EUIU/Integrating-Amazon-Cognito-User-Pools-with-API-Gateway) of Authorizer Labmda function. The question is how to implement that function into Serverless framework. Any example is appreciated.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First go to the Authorizer tab of API Gateway and add cognito UserPool authorizer. Make a note of the resource id from the breadcrumb. Then inside the s-function.json you could use

```
 "authorizationType": "COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
 "authorizerId": "<resource_id_of_authorizer>",
```

Comment: This is if you are using serverless 0.5v